# Pass Image data with Json object in AJAX (Multipart data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, multipartform-data

I have **AJAX** request currently:

> {
>     name:"test",
>     records:{
>         key1:value1,
>         key2:value2,
>         imageKey: imageValue
>     }
>   }

I want to pass Image as **multipart** data with same JSON object.

is it possible to pass **image** like above json but multipart object?

Please help

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/upload-file-and-json-data-in-the-same-post-request-using-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your image to `base64` and pass it along your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your object should be something like below. your image should be in **base64** string

```
var serverObj={
 name:"Test",
 phone:"3533543543",
 imageData:getBase64Image(imgElem)
}
var imgData = JSON.stringify(serverObj);

function getBase64Image(imgElem) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = imgElem.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = imgElem.clientHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imgElem, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/5jberd67/5/)